# Select and insert okay, but update not working in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to update my record in database, where I'm updating the `balance` column. I managed to do select and insert command but update isn't working.
Here is my code.

```
unit widrawMoneyPanel;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,
  System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit, data_module;

type
  TForm8 = class(TForm)
    money: TEdit;
    widraw: TButton;
    back: TButton;
    procedure widrawClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure backClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    id: integer;
  end;

var
  Form8: TForm8;
  currentBalance: Double;

implementation

uses customerpanel, updatecustomer;
{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm8.backClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  form7.balance.Text := floattostr(currentBalance);
  form7.show;

end;

procedure TForm8.widrawClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  DataModule1.ADOQuery1db.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id = :ids';

  DataModule1.ADOQuery1db.Parameters.ParamByName('ids').Value := id;

  try
    DataModule1.ADOQuery1db.open;
    currentBalance := strtofloat(DataModule1.ADOQuery1db.FieldByName('balance')
      .AsString);

    currentBalance := currentBalance - strtofloat(money.Text);

  finally
    DataModule1.ADOQuery1db.close;
  end;

  DataModule1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Text :=
    'update customer set balance = :currentBalance where id= :ids';
  DataModule1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('currentBalance').Value :=
    currentBalance;
  DataModule1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('ids').Value := id;

  DataModule1.ADOQuery1db.ExecSQL;

end;

end.
```

Comment: Debug your code.

Comment: "not working" is not a problem or error description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning your `UPDATE` SQL to `DataModule1.ADOQuery1`, but then you are calling `ExecSQL()` on `DataModule1.ADOQuery1db` instead, which still has your `SELECT` SQL assigned to it.

Comment: Well spotted Remi :-)

Comment: Yes that was it. Thank you